# `immediateFlush` yields different z order

Tags: c#, itext, itext7

I am using iText 7.2.1.

I have two paragraphs. The first one is at fixed position and the second one is normal.

I notice that the `immediateFlush` parameter in `Document` constructor yields different z order of elements. I don't know if it is normal.

When `immediateFlush` is `true`, the latter paragraph `BBBBBB` is on top of the former paragraph `AAAAAA`.

[image]

When `immediateFlush` is `false`, their z order is the opposite.

[image]

```
using iText.Kernel.Colors;
using iText.Kernel.Pdf;
using iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas;
using iText.Layout;
using iText.Kernel.Pdf.Xobject;
using iText.Layout.Element;
using iText.Kernel.Font;
using iText.IO.Font;

namespace iTextTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var writer = new PdfWriter("test.pdf");
            var pdf_doc = new PdfDocument(writer);
            var doc = new Document(pdf_doc, iText.Kernel.Geom.PageSize.DEFAULT, true);

            var p1 = new Paragraph("AAAAAA");
            p1.SetFixedPosition(40, 785, 200);
            p1.SetFontColor(iText.Kernel.Colors.ColorConstants.RED);
            doc.Add(p1);

            var p2 = new Paragraph("BBBBBB");
            doc.Add(p2);

            doc.Close();
            pdf_doc.Close();
            writer.Close();

            MessageBox.Show("OK");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [Documentation for reference](https://api.itextpdf.com/iText7/dotnet/7.2.1/classi_text_1_1_layout_1_1_document.html#a84a69ceaf573160cc43edd422107f28c)

Comment: @AndréLemos Thanks. Maybe fixed position paragraphs are not page-related, so this parameter does affect the relative order of elements.

Comment: Both paragraph types are page related. If `immediateFlush` is `true`, all paragraphs are likely to be drawn in the order they are added in the code. Otherwise, fixed-position paragraphs are collected separately and drawn after the non-fixed-position content.